# Using blank MVC routes with HttpGet requests to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, http-get

I'm having some trouble hitting an endpoint from javascript after changing up some routes.  I have two controllers, and I'm trying to hit an endpoint off a controller that has only the variable passed in its url.

RouteConfig.cs file:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Home Page",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "HomePage", action = "Home" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Example Page",
            url: "{exampleId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ExamplePage", action = "Index"}
        );
```

HomePageController will be hit by mysite.com.

ExamplePageController will be hit by mysite.com/value, which generates the page based off the exampleId value.

All I need to do now is to hit the endpoint in my ExamplePageController:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult myEndpoint(string exampleId) {
        var result = _exampleProvider.exampleFunction(exampleId);

        return result;
    }
```

So what would the Url look like for if I were to hit this endpoint from the javascript?  Here are some that I have tried:

www.mysite.com/ExamplePage/myEndpoint?exampleId=value

www.mysite.com/myEndpoint?exampleId=value

The top Url is the one that I used to use, but changing up the url value in RouteConfig for the routes stopped the endpoint from being able to be hit.

Any ideas here?
Thanks!

Comment: If `mysite.com/value` works when you try in a browser, it should work when you call it from javascript as well.

Comment: Mysite.com/value would be the main controller method, but I am trying to hit a different method in that controller through an HttpGet request

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue -- it seems that the Url needs to be "{exampleId}/{action}", and the home page needs to be on the bottom of the list of routes.

The action parameter in the url is the function name, so when hitting from the javascript it will look like 
www.mysite.com/value/myEndpoint?exampleId=value

I was never allowing for the method name to be a parameter in the route.

The home page route should also have the action parameter in the route Url if there will be other javascript calls to that controller.  It should looks like this: "{action}"